# dired backward/forward function

Tags: emacs, dired

I'm looking for a package the browser's "back" button for dired.  i.e. some
way to go back to a previously visited directory.

The usecase I have in mind is to traverse deeper into a directory tree after
invoking <kbd>^</kbd> to to to a parent folder.

Comment: to whoever voted to close: I thought it was decided to keep the Emacs questions on the same site (i.e. here on stackoverflow)?  It seems really horrible to have to search a separate site to ask about Emacs when almost all answers would involve some emacs-lisp code.

Comment: How does `^` not do what you want?  Can you explain further or give an example?

Comment: From the child, I press `^` to go to the parent.  I'm looking for a way back to the child.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use `q` to just close the current window, and the last visited one will be here.

Comment: I cannot fault your logic.  Will keep the question open for a while in case there is a more comprehensive package.

Answer (score 2):

I use `a` to drill down into directories, then rebind `^` to this to go back up:

```lisp
(defun my-dired-up-dir ()
  "Go up a directory."
  (interactive)
  (let ((current-dir (dired-current-directory)))
    (find-alternate-file "..")
    (dired-goto-file current-dir)))
```

It goes up a directory and puts point on the directory you just came from (so you can `a` back down if you want).  Perhaps not exactly what you want since it only works on one level, but might still be useful.

Comment: If you `(require 'dired-x)` then you can use `C-x C-j` to run `dired-jump` in dired buffers and also file buffers, which takes you to the dired buffer for the current parent directory, with point on the file/directory you came from.